# How the triangle definition relates with its existence

Tags: triangles

In Plane and solid geometry by Fletcher Durell(p.32), it states that:

> A triangle is a portion of plane bounded by three straight lines, as
>   the triangle ABC".

How does this statement relates with the existence of a triangle. For example, how could three sides be chosen so the figure obtained is *a portion of a plane bounded by three straight lines*?

Comment: I don't know what your question is. That definition tells you what the author means by the word "triangle". Presumably the "$ABC$" in your quote refers to an example (a picture).

Comment: You just have to choose three lines, no two of which are parallel.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @EthanBolker: In simple words, having three lines, how a triangle be made where the lines could take any measure?

Comment: @EthanBolker: I'm sorry. I'm rephrasing the comment. In simple words, how could a triangle be made using three lines of any measure?

Comment: You keep trying, but I still don't understand the question. If you have three line segments and the sum of two of the lengths is less than the length of the third then they can make a triangle. If this isn't what you mean there's nothing more I can do to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Is there a proof for the _second_ sentence in your previous comment?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Why is it _not_ possible to construct a triangle for three line segments where the sum of the lengths of two is less than one?

Comment: @EthanBolke: I hope it's something related to the intersection of circles as stated in this [answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-construct-a-triangle-with-the-side-lengths-of-7-8-and-15). I'm still working on it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Answer (score 0):

In order for a portion of the plane to be bounded by three straight lines, the lines in question need only:

- not be parallel to each other
- intersect in more than one point (i.e. 3 points; if you wish the area of the bounded region to be nonzero)*

*Proofs available upon request.

Examples

As a construction:
How to make a triangle (in a plane):

Choose (or draw) 2 non-parallel lines. These lines intersect in a point.

Choose an additional line that:

- Does not intersect the aforementioned point. (unless you want the bounded area to be zero)
- Is not parallel to either of the prior 2 lines.

For example, in the Cartesian plane:
If you use the x and y axis for the first two lines, then they intersect in the origin. If the third line you choose isn't parallel to either axis, and doesn't run through the origin, it can be written in the form y=ax+b or x=cy+d, such that  a, b, c, and d are $\neq 0$.

For another construction:

Choose two non-parallel lines.
Pick a point on each line, other than the intersection, and draw a line through those points.
The area bounded by the lines ought to be between the third line you draw, and the intersection (of the first two lines you chose).

There are some illustrated examples here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate and here:
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Elements.pdf **under Proposition 1.**
I understand this book (Euclid's Elements) is filled with constructions and constructive proofs.

A Pictures of 3 lines, no 2 of which are parallel:
[image: a triangle]
Note that if all three lines intersected in the same place, there wouldn't be any bounded region of non-zero area.

Comment: Yeah please give me proof for the (area of bounded region - nonzero). I hope this is what makes a three line figure to exist.

Comment: For a proof, I need starting assumptions. Is it clear that in order to be a region of zero area, the region would have to be a point or a line?

Comment: Yes of course. I hope an area should be bounded by at least 3 lines.

Comment: At least three? The question as stated, concerns *only* the necessary conditions for triangles, *not* the minimum necessary number of lines to make a region of non-zero area (which is also 3).

Comment: More precisely, how to choose three lines(side length) so it intersects. I hope this should be analyzed by checking whether the two sides intersect at a point by knowing their loci.

Comment: Up 'til now, I've used the word line to denote a line of infinite length - this is what guarantees that 'two parallel lines intersect in a point' (in e.g. (euclidean geometry)). If I understand this new form of your question, you want to know how to take three equations (each describing a line) and figure out 1) do they make a triangle, and if so 2) where the lines intersect, and 3) what the lengths of each side of the triangle are. Would this suffice? (And should we move this to chat?)

Comment: A loci is a set of (all) points satisfying a condition - what conditions generate the loci you're talking about?

Comment: Loci generated by the set of points rising from either end point of the base of the triangle. I hope the loci would be a circle at each end point of the base of the triangle. The point where these two loci(circle) meet would generate the third point of the triangle. Is it possible to see whether the loci meets just by solving the equation of two sides of a triangle? I hope you would need  6 equations altogether(2 for each pair of side).

Comment: If you just choose 3 points at random, they will almost certainly make a triangle. If you choose 3 distinct non-colinear points it is guaranteed. **I think the information you're looking for is somewhere on this page: [http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/formulas.html](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/formulas.html).** It contains enough information to tell if it is possible (and if so, how - ) to make a triangle given three side lengths.

Comment: I couldn't see any information regarding the construction of triangles. The [webpage](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/formulas.html) shows a list of formulas for a triangle.

Comment: If you want to draw a triangle using circles: draw 2 circles (with the same radius) that include each other's center. Draw a point at the center of *each* triangle, and another point at one of the two intersections of the circles. Connect these points. You now have an equilateral triangle.

Comment: If you want to use equations, 3 equations with 2 variables each will be sufficient - one equation for each line.

Comment: I'm trying to look, how three lines constitute a triangle.

Comment: One line for each side. 3 lines with 3 intersections means 3 sides and 3 points.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I'm trying to look, how 3 sides makes 3 intersection altogether in 1 triangle. Is there any equation on, how to makes 3 sides with 3 intersections altogether in 1 triangle?